# Putting a Code to the Right of an Item in a New Enumerate Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, listings, enumerate, tcolorbox

Consider

[image]

I would like to present the string of 12 colored bullets a little to the right of the enumerated tcolorbox and vertically centered.

The code which produces the above picture is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}


% % The colored box that encloses the item number.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=red,
    colback=red!35,
    top=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}


% % FANCY ENUMERATE positioning the enumerated colored box above the text.
\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
  \setlength\parskip\bigskipamount
%  \begin{center}%
}{%
%  \end{center}%
}
\newcommand\citem{%
  \refstepcounter{cenum}%
  \par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}

% NEW SYMBOLS DEFINITION
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{1.0}{\bullet}}}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{1.0}{\bullet}}}}
  
\begin{document}
\large

 
$\red\blue\red\blue$ $\blue\red\blue\blue$ $\red\red\red\blue$

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{cenumerate}
\citem \lipsum[4] 
\end{cenumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I have tried replacing `\citem` with `\citem[$\red\blue\red\blue$ $\blue\red\blue\blue$ $\red\red\red\blue$]`, and also placing `$\red\blue\red\blue$ $\blue\red\blue\blue$ $\red\red\red\blue$` to the right of `\citem` but neither of these produce what I am looking for.

QUESTION: How may I modify the above code so that I can place a uniquely colored binary string of colored bullets to the right of each enumerated item in a "fancy" listing such as this in the manner described?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `\citem[$...` if you define `\citem` to have an optional argument, so `\newcommand\citem{1][]{... #1`

Comment: @David Carlisle Is `{1]` correct? Also, I am not sure what `{... #1` means. Perhaps you will consider posting this as an expanded answer. Thank you.

Comment: `[1]` not `{1]` sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "little" to the right and vertically centered.

Using the new command `\citemx{<bullets patttern>}`

[image: y]

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}


% % The colored box that encloses the item number.
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, %sharpcorners,
    colframe=red,
    colback=red!35,
    top=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    tcbox raise base}


% % FANCY ENUMERATE positioning the enumerated colored box above the text.
\newcounter{cenum}
\newcommand\cenumsep{}  
\newenvironment{cenumerate}{%
    \setcounter{cenum}{0}%
    \setlength\parskip\bigskipamount
    %  \begin{center}%
}{%
    %  \end{center}%
}

\newcommand\citemx[1]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\refstepcounter{cenum}%
\par\cenumsep\logo{\arabic{cenum}}%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \hspace*{20pt}#1  % left/right space
    \vspace*{0.5ex}% vertical adjustment
\end{minipage}
\par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip\medskip\noindent\ignorespaces% \medskip is the distance between label and text, change as needed
}


% NEW SYMBOLS DEFINITION
\newcommand{\red}{\textcolor{red}{{\scalefont{1.0}{\bullet}}}}
\newcommand{\blue}{\textcolor{blue}{{\scalefont{1.0}{\bullet}}}}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \large
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{cenumerate}
            \citemx{$\red\blue\red\blue$ $\blue\red\blue\blue$ $\red\red\red\blue$} \lipsum[4] 
            \citemx{$\blue\blue\blue\blue$ $\red\red\red\blue$ $\red\blue\red\red$} \lipsum[1] 
            \citemx{$\blue\red\red\red$ $\blue\blue\red\blue$ $\red\red\red\red$} \lipsum[2] 
            
        \end{cenumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. For some reason, the system did not notify me that your answer had been posted. Regarding your answer, how may the header, side-margin, and text boxes be eliminated. I'm not sure why they are there.

Comment: I just figured out why the frames are being displayed. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for this most helpful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians Sorry I did not mention `showframe`

Comment: No problem. It didn't take me long to figure it out once I took a closer look at the code. Thanks again for your answer.